# TensorBoard Callback in Keras does not respect initial_epoch of fit?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I'm trying to train multiple models in parallel on a single graphics card. To achieve that I need to resume training of models from saved weights which is not a problem. The `model.fit()` method has even a parameter initial_epoch that lets me tell the model which epoch the loaded model is on. However when i pass a TensorBoard callback to the `fit()` method in order to monitor the training of the models, on Tensorboard all data is shown on x=0.

Is there a ways to overcome this and adjust the epoch on tensorboard?

By the way: Im running Keras 2.0.6 and Tensorflow 1.3.0.

```python
self.callbacks = [TensorBoardCallback(log_dir='./../logs/'+self.model_name, histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=False, start_epoch=self.step_num)]
self.model.fit(x=self.data['X_train'], y=self.data['y_train'], batch_size=self.input_params[-1]['batch_size'], epochs=1, validation_data=(self.data['X_test'], self.data['y_test']), verbose=verbose, callbacks=self.callbacks, shuffle=self.hyperparameters['shuffle_data'], initial_epoch=self.step_num)
self.model.save_weights('./weights/%s.hdf5'%(self.model_name))
self.model.load_weights('./weights/%s.hdf5'%(self.model_name))
self.model.fit(x=self.data['X_train'], y=self.data['y_train'], batch_size=self.input_params[-1]['batch_size'], epochs=1, validation_data=(self.data['X_test'], self.data['y_test']), verbose=verbose, callbacks=self.callbacks, shuffle=self.hyperparameters['shuffle_data'], initial_epoch=self.step_num)
self.model.save_weights('./weights/%s.hdf5'%(self.model_name))
```

The resulting graph on Tensorboard looks like this which is not what i was hoping for:
[image]

**Update:**

When passing `epochs=10` to the first `model.fit()` the 10 epoch results are displayed in TensorBoard (see picture).

However when reloading the model and running it (with the same callback attached) the `on_epoch_end` method of the callback gets never called.

[image]

Comment: Which version of keras are you running? I'm looking at the [master's branch](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L748) and the Tensorboard callback doesn't a `start_epoch` parameter (instead, it is passed to `Tensorboard#on_epoch_end` by the caller.

Comment: I'm running Keras 2.0.6 but as mentioned in the post the initial_epoch parameter is not passed to the callback but to the model.fit() method of keras.

Comment: I know `initial_epoch` is fit's parameter, but the first line in your code snippet is `self.callbacks = [TensorBoardCallback(... start_epoch=self.step_num)]`, which is weird.
Another question about this parallel training: do these models have different names? Are there multiple directories inside `logs`?

Comment: Oh yes you are right sorry. I tried to play a bit with the TensorBoard Callback itself and tried to replace the epoch in on_epoch_end() with my epoch number. Though that method doesnt seem to get called when i train a reloaded model. I did not mean to leave that in the code sorry.
Yes every model has a different name and all of them are displayed on the Tensorboard graph but only for epoch 0.

Comment: Don't worry. Back to the problem: I am thinking the models were being recreated (therefore, being renamed) before being resumed. If you want them to reapear as the same line in the graph, they must have the same name => be contained in the same subfolder. Still, from the graph, you don't seem to have trained any model for even one epoch. Try to train them for more than one epoch and check if a line (an not only a point) appears in the graph; drag `smoothing` to 0 and check `step` instead of `relative` at "Horizontal axis".  Then upload the new graph to your question.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question. Again it seem like the on_epoch_end() function of the callback only gets called for the "fresh" model and not for the reloaded one...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160953/discussion-between-ldavid-and-raspel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that when i pass the number of episodes to model.fit() to tell it how long to train, it has to be the number FROM the initial_epoch specified. So if initial_epoch=self.step_num then , epochs=self.step_num+10 if i want to train for 10 episodes.

Comment: "Note that in conjunction with `initial_epoch`, `epochs` is to be understood as "final epoch". The model is not trained for a number of iterations given by epochs, but merely until the epoch of index epochs is reached." - [the docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit)

Comment: So use `epochs=step + epochs` and `initial_epoch=step * epochs`.

Answer (score 0):

Say we just started fitting our model and our first time epoch count  is 30
(please ignore other paramterers just look at **epochs** and **initial_epoch**)
model.fit(train_dataloader,validation_data = test_dataloader,epochs =30,steps_per_epoch = len(train_dataloader),callbacks = callback_list)

Now say ,after 30 epoch we want to start again from 31st epoch (you can see  this in tesnorboard) by changing our Adam optimizer(or nay optimizer) learning rate

so we can do is

model.optimizer.learning_rate = 0.0005

model1.fit(train_dataloader,validation_data = test_dataloader,initial_epoch=**30**,epochs =**55**,steps_per_epoch = len(train_dataloader),callbacks = callback_list)

=> So here initial_epoch= where we have left training last time;
epochs= initial_epoch+num_epoch we want to run for this second fit